# Consume WCF service by Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, wcf

I created a WCF service, that is supposed to be consumed by Javascript(Json) on client side. Websites are generated by ASP.NET MVC. I got everything running on localhost IIS-Express. 
Problem is, when I call this WCF service from Javascript, it throws and undefined error.
One of many thoughts, why this error occurs is, that WCF web.config is not set correctly and doesn't allow cross site scripting.

Here is web.config file

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
       <configuration>
         <system.serviceModel>        
           <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default"
            name="Wcf_Categories.Categories">
        <endpoint address=""
                  behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="Wcf_Categories.ICategories" />    
        <endpoint address="sc"
                  behaviorConfiguration="script"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="crossDomain"
                  contract="Wcf_Categories.ICategories"/>    
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"
                        address="mex" />    
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="script">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>      
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If I call service directly from browser for example localhost:1813/Categories.svc/sc/GetData?name=undefined
it returns suggested data and behaves normally (sites running at localhost/TestSites/Products# )

Here is script for wcf service call

```
function GetCategories(categoryName) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: "false",
    url: "localhost:1813/Categories.svc/sc/GetData",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data : 'name='+categoryName,
    processData: true,
    success: function (result) {
        ServiceSucceeded(result);
    },
    error: ServiceFailed
});
 }

function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
 var resultObject;
 if (DataType == "json") {
    resultObject = result.GetUserResult;    
    for (i = 0; i < resultObject.length; i++) {
        alert(resultObject[i]);
    }    
   }    
 }

function ServiceFailed(xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);<---------------------- Alert output is "undefined". Exception details = [Exception... "<no message>" nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/TestSites/content/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js :: .send :: line 6" data: no] ------->
if (xhr.responseText) {
    var err = xhr.responseText;
    if (err)
        error(err);
    else
        error({ Message: "Unknown server error." });
}

return;
}
```

Comment: One potential problem with your script is that `data` is no of application/json type as declared

Comment: If your WCF and web servers are on different ports, that would be a cross-domain issue, yes.